# Add Control object into DataGridViewTextBoxCell

Tags: c#, textbox, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have a class that is deriveded from `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` and I want to add an `Form.Control` object (like TextBox, CheckBox ..) into that cell but there is no control object that I can add new one into it.

In other words I want to create a cell that contains multiple control object. Is there any way to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using normal Windows.Forms controls is not possible. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx), where it says: *you must define classes that derive from DataGridViewColumn and DataGridViewCell*. Or *define a class that derives from Control and implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl interface*. Reason is that the control must be able to cooperate with the hosting grid in exchanging values, handling edit mode, style etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I had examined the documentation but as I understand this solution can be valid when cell is in edit mode but in fact I never edit the cell, I just want to show a string in a cell in a format that is each character is shown in a single TextBox or Label doesn't matter.

"http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/424/unled2zg.jpg"

it's like "pf_feen_token" column.

Comment: heres the link.... http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/424/unled2zg.jpg ...I also want that kind of datagridview custom column...